# How to add a field to Discussion Board

Tags: custom-field-types, discussion-board

I have got Discussion Board in Community Site. I want to add a field with image, or picture to the discussion list. How could I add a field to discussion list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Community Site you can View All Site Contents. Then open the Dicussion List.

Select the List Settings and "Create New Column". Provide a Name and Choose Type as "Link", then choose it be Shown as a Picture.

Make sure to add it to Add Content Type and Display in the Default View.

Comment: it's not work. I don't see another field in Subject View.

Comment: I must IT show in Subject view.

Comment: Its seems the Subject View can't be modified. Try creating a new View and make it the default one. Or create a custom View using JSLink or customize the XSL of Subject View.

Comment: But the Subject view is well prepered.  I only want to this view add one field.

Comment: How customize the XSL of Subject View?